# Problems detecting object duplication in array during pruning/migration

Tags: java, arrays, object

This following of my program should recieve an array of objects and sort them based on the size of their **privilege** variable. The "arrayFromBefore" variable is filled with objects of type `MyClass`. It just basically creates a new MyClass object and returns it with the same attributes of the object.

The problem is, in certain cases, there seems to be several occurences of the same MyClass object in the priority array. These duplications are also not always the same multiple (e.g. one object occurs 3 times in a row, another 5 times in a row, another twice, etc...)

```
MyClass[] priorityArray = new MyClass[arrayFromBefore.length];

for (int i = 0; i < priorityArray.length; i++) {
  int maxIndex = 0;
  int maxPrivilege = arrayFromBefore[i].returnPrivilege();
  for (int j = 1; j < arrayFromBefore.length; j++) {
    int currentPrivilege = arrayFromBefore[j].returnPrivilege();
    if (currentPrivilege > maxPrivilege) {
      maxPrivilege = currentPrivilege;
      maxIndex = j;
    }
  }
  MyClass mostPrivilaged = arrayFromBefore[maxIndex];
  priorityArray[i] = mostPrivileged;
  arrayFromBefore[maxIndex].setPriority(-900000000);
}
```

Comment: So they repeat, and how does that affect your result? Could you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: It would help if you actually put in working code and compile it before dumping it here to catch and reduce errors so you don't waste everyone's time with an inadvertent mistake. It's clear you didn't do that because you typed 'myClass' on one line and that wouldn't compile. You also spelled length as lentgh, which I fixed too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your inner `for-loop` where for each `i`, `j` starts from same value `1`. `j` should start exactly from next to `i`, so that same object cannot be overrided.

```
MyClass[] priorityArray = new MyClass[arrayFromBefore.length];
   for (int i=0; i<priorityArray.length - 1; i++) {
   int maxIndex = 0;
   int maxPrivilege = arrayFromBefore[i].returnPrivilege();
   for (int j=1+i; j<arrayFromBefore.legnth; j++) {
       int currentPrivilege = arrayFromBefore[j].returnPrivilege();
       if (currentPrivilege > maxPrivilege) {
           maxPrivilege = currentPrivilege;
           maxIndex = j;
       }
   }

// priorityArray[i] = mostPrivileged;  this line can be removed as it isn't required because you are getting sorted arrayFromBefore.  

myClass mostPrivilaged = arrayFromBefore[maxIndex];   // Swapping of        
arrayFromBefore[maxIndex] = arrayFromBefore[i];       // largest priority object
arrayFromBefore[i] = mostPrivilaged;                  // with its required position in sorted array.

}
```

After this you will get `arrayFromBefore` as shorted in descending order of priority.